# Call JPanel inside JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I imagine that it's a simple thing to do, but i did not find something that help me in google.

I have a class that extends JPanel like a menu, the users than click in a start button and calls another class extending JPanel, but it does not work. 
I call the first class in my main method that is a simple JFrame, the code is bellow:

```
JFrame tela = new JFrame("teste");
    tela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    tela.setSize(800,600);
    tela.add(new InitialScreen());

    tela.setVisible(true);
```

And in InitialScreen i have a button with the following actionEvent:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    this.add(new BackgroundGame());
    this.validate();
    this.revalidate();
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

but with this I press the button and nothing occurs.

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Without more detailed code here are my tips: 1. Check that your buttons still connect to jButton1ActionPerformed 2. Check what Layout you have for your components.

Comment: The button works, When i put System.exit(0) it exits the application, and what do u mean with layout components? In the main i only have JFrame, in InitialScreen only this button and backgroundGame is my game class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to incorporate something like this in your code:

```
    JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
    InitialScreen panel = new InitialScreen(); // I am assuming this is a JPanel
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            // TODO add your logic
        }
    });
    panel.add(button);
    tela.add(panel);
```

Be careful using the `this` operator. If you follow my example, you won't be able to use `this`.  You will need to either use the `ActionEvent` object to get the source object, or you will need to reference some global variable; for example `tela` in your case.

Also, I don't think is a good idea to make `InitialScreen` an anonymous object.  You should create an explicit instance like I did above.

The button SHOULD be declared inside the panel and the logic I showed should be in the `InitialScreen` panel class.  In the frame, the only thing you will need to do is create an instance of `InitialScreen` and add it to your frame.

Comment: making my own button despite to use netBeans layout generator it worked. I hate to use this layout of netBeans =/ 
Thanks Everyone!